# Download progress for JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

Is there any way that I can show a progress bar while a JSON object is being downloaded in the client?

The JSON is around 5mb and instead of show a loading gif, I would like to provide the user a % of completion.

Answer (score 0):

you can have look at this.From what i understand is you want to show deterministic progress bar,for this you need to the source size.You can have a look at this http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/